# Comment transposer ou traduire « recipe for a potential tinderbox » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

> Sarah McCool, a professor of public health at Georgia State
> University, said the combination [low vaccination rates, the
> relaxation of mask rules and other precautions, and the swift spread
> of the more-contagious delta variant] amounts to a "recipe for a
> potential tinderbox." (sur [cbc.ca](https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/coronavirus-covid19-canada-world-july14-2021-1.6101961))

Le [*tinderbox*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tinderbox) (voir aussi [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinderbox), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tinderbox#English)), c'est un *contenant*, *ce qui est sec au point de pouvoir prendre en feu*, ou comme le *baril de poudre*, et [*recipe for*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/recipe) réfère ici à la manière de faire quelque chose qui a comme conséquence, comme résultat le nom associé, nous dit-on (Merriam Learners).

Comment traduit-on ou transpose-t-on « ...amounts to [avoir le même effet, être équivalent à] a "recipe for a potential tinderbox". » ?

Comment: amounts to = être l'équivalent de

Comment: @Lambie C'est déjà mentionné dans le dernière ligne de la question...

Answer (score 3):

C'est un peu plus pessimiste que l'anglais mais la première chose qui me vient à l'esprit est cette formule :

> Vous avez là tous les *ingrédients d'une **catastrophe annoncée***.

Answer (score 2):

- *cette combinaison a tout d'une situation explosive en puissance*

> (Harrap's) **tinderbox** *Fig:* situation explosive

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/puissance)) **en puissance** Loc. adj. Synon. potentiel, virtuel.